# How to prevent Fiber from auto registerting HEAD routes?

Tags: go, go-fiber

Fiber v2 (https://gofiber.io/) automatically adds a HEAD route for each GET route.
Is it possible to prevent this?

I want only the GETs to be registered. Actually, I want to register only those routes I add explicitly.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the implementation of [(*App).Get](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/blob/f4a9cb5023b871430b669d5ca36db1478033dad4/app.go#L707-L711):

```golang
// Get registers a route for GET methods that requests a representation
// of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data.
func (app *App) Get(path string, handlers ...Handler) Router {
    return app.Head(path, handlers...).Add(MethodGet, path, handlers...)
}
```

And [(*Group).Get](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/blob/f4a9cb5023b871430b669d5ca36db1478033dad4/group.go#L95-L100):

```golang
// Get registers a route for GET methods that requests a representation
// of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data.
func (grp *Group) Get(path string, handlers ...Handler) Router {
    grp.Add(MethodHead, path, handlers...)
    return grp.Add(MethodGet, path, handlers...)
}
```

There is no way to prevent this behavior. All you can do is to avoid using them and use the `Add` method directly. For example, register a `GET` route like this:

```golang
app.Add(fiber.MethodGet, "/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    return c.SendString("Hello, World!")
})
```

---

Please note that [(*App).Use](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/blob/f4a9cb5023b871430b669d5ca36db1478033dad4/app.go#L664-L705) and [(*Group).Use](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber/blob/f4a9cb5023b871430b669d5ca36db1478033dad4/group.go#L48-L93) match all HTTP verbs. You can remove the `HEAD` method like this:

```golang
methods := make([]string, 0, len(fiber.DefaultMethods)-1)
for _, m := range fiber.DefaultMethods {
    if m != fiber.MethodHead {
        methods = append(methods, m)
    }
}
app := fiber.New(fiber.Config{
    RequestMethods: methods,
})
```

**Note**: it panics whenever a `HEAD` route is registered since it's not included in `RequestMethods`.

---

I don't know why you want to do this. Maybe a better choice is to use a middleware to reject all `HEAD` requests like this:

```golang
app.Use(func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    if c.Method() == fiber.MethodHead {
        c.Status(fiber.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return nil
    }
    return c.Next()
})
```